# Translate In Underscore Template - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript

What is the recommended / best practise method of translating within a underscore template for example within a modal popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the strings translatable in underscore template (Knockout template) use data-bind attribute with i18n binding handler, for example:

```
<span class="admin__action-dropdown-text" data-bind="i18n: 'Columns'"></span>
```

If you need to translate HTML text outside of HTML element you can do it using the comment syntax:

```
<!-- ko i18n: 'You have no items in your shopping cart.' --><!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: And this is integrated with the rest of magento translations? You beautiful person!

Comment: Yep, you can refer official documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use translation in underscore

```
<%= _.i18n('Hello') %>
```

Thanks